# What's a good plan for losing 50 pounds in 3 months without diet?

Tags: weight-loss

I'm a 5"10 16 year old male weighing at 180 pounds (81.6kg). I'm not terribly fat, however I do appear to be a wider guy when compared to most of my friends. I begin working full-time this summer (7:00AM-4:00PM, 5d/wk) and I want to squeeze a plan to lose about 50 pounds within that schedule. However, I also do not want to go on a diet.
I am willing to do any kind of physical exercise needed to obtain my goal, but I would prefer to not have to diet. Here's why:

- My parents are in charge of my dinner and breakfast options, and I don't want to make them get other foods to fit my diet.
- I cannot afford to buy healthy for breakfast, lunch, and dinner every day.
- I want to spend the *absolute minimal* amount of money on this weight loss plan.

I don't necessarily eat bad, everyday for lunch I get a 6-inch turkey sub (cheese, olives, and lettuce) with a coke from subway. I usually have toast for breakfast, and dinner I just eat whatever is available. I don't snack too often, and I eat quite a bit of fruit.

What exercise routine would you recommend to meet this goal?

Comment: Your goals are unrealistic. Why do you want to be 5'10" and 130? That is...skeletal. And, you arent going to lose 50 lbs in 3 months, no matter what some tabloid might say.

Comment: @JohnP My friends who I referred to have the type of body I'm going for and claim to be 130 or less.. but based off of what you just said I'm assuming they lied (same height, and they aren't muscly).

Comment: I was 5' 8" and ~135 in high school and worked out, honestly wished I weighed more. Might want to aim for 150. Also 1lb of body fat has 3500 calories so if you keep eating the same, the exersize may need to be vigorous. Cardio, weights, etc. Fasting for 40 days without exercise would lose you around 30lbs, perhaps more if you're still growing

Comment: The answer you want is "Cardio and weightlifting". The answer you don't seem to want to hear is you need to eat less and eat better. Ditch the coke (or make it diet), snacks and ask your parents for smaller portion sizes. If you parents are forcibly overfeeding you then eat less at lunch. The overall calorie intake over days/weeks is what matters anyway. The saying is the same as it has always been: **"What should I eat to lose weight?", EAT LESS**

Comment: @Craig that model doesn't really hold true for dieting purposes.

Answer (score -1):

Let's say you currently eat as much as you burn power day. Meaning your weight is constant. One kg of fat contains about 7000 kcal. You want to lose 22kg.

So that makes 154.000 kcal. 3 months have 90 days. That's 1700 kcal per day you need to burn additionally.

That's a little more than 2 hours of jogging every day or something equally demanding.  All based on unreliable first hit Google links. Might be off by quite margin but give you a general idea.

Comment: The correlation is faulty. While 1 kg of fat may yield 7000 cals in a food furnace,  that doesn't translate directly to weight loss. That is bad informatiin based on poor science.